# Writing to .xlsx using java. BiffViewer error occurs

Tags: java, apache-poi

jars I have used : `dom4j poi-3.8.jar` `poi-ooxml-3.8.jar` `poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8.jar` `xbean.jar`

The code :

```
package org.capgemini.ui;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class XSSFWorkBookWriter  {

public void writeWorkBook(Vector table) throws Exception {      

XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet();
table=new Vector();
table.add(new String("Howdy"));
table.add(new java.sql.Date(2012,06,20));
table.add(new Double(13.35D));
table.add(new String("Fine"));
table.add(new java.sql.Date(2012,06,20));
table.add(new Double(13.38D));

Iterator rows=table.iterator();
Enumeration rowsOfVector=table.elements();
int totalNoOfRows=table.size()/2;
int currentRow=0;
while (rows.hasNext () && currentRow<totalNoOfRows){
XSSFRow row =  sheet.createRow(currentRow++);               
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
XSSFCell cell=row.createCell(i);
Object val=rows.next();
if( val instanceof String){
cell.setCellValue(val.toString());
            }
else if(val instanceof Date){
cell.setCellValue((java.sql.Date)val);
            }
else if(val instanceof Double){
cell.setCellValue((Double)val);
}
}
}

FileOutputStream outPutStream = null;
    try {
        outPutStream = new FileOutputStream("D:/Try.xlsx");
        workBook.write(outPutStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (outPutStream != null) {
            try {
                outPutStream.flush();
                outPutStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    XSSFWorkBookWriter bookWriter=new XSSFWorkBookWriter();
    try {
        bookWriter.writeWorkBook(new Vector());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

ERROR ::

> ```
> org.apache.poi.hssf.dev.BiffViewer$CommandParseException: Biff viewer needs a filename
>  at org.apache.poi.hssf.dev.BiffViewer$CommandArgs.parse(BiffViewer.java:333)
>  at org.apache.poi.hssf.dev.BiffViewer.main(BiffViewer.java:386)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

BiffViewer is part of HSSF, which only works with the older .xls files (OLE2 based). You're generating a .xlsx file with XSSF, which is a different low level format.

If you really want to use BiffViewer (not sure why, it's normally only used with debugging, but still), then you'll need to change your XSSF code to be HSSF code. Otherwise, if you did mean to be using XSSF to generate a .xlsx file, then you can't use the HSSF debugging tools. If you want to know what's in your .xlsx file, unzip it (.xlsx is a zip of xml files) and view the XML.